# SQL - Rank or Row_Number not bringing back desired data

Tags: t-sql, rank, row-number

I'm writing a query that will bring me back either row or rank '1'. When I run the query with the 'where rank or row clause equals 1', no data returns for those columns but if I take out the 'where rank or row clause' the data populates. Can someone tell me why the where clause is causing no data to return?

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT CLMED.SIMPLE_GENERIC_C
                 , MEDINFO.MEDICATION_ID as [CYTOTEC]
                 ,FMED.PAT_ENC_CSN_ID
                , FMED.HOSP_ADMSN_DATE
               -- , MIN(FMED.TAKEN_DATETIME) over (Partition by FMED.PAT_ENC_CSN_ID, 
                 MEDINFO.MEDICATION_ID ) as 'FIRST DOSE'
                , MIN(FMED.TAKEN_DATETIME) over (Partition by FMED.PAT_ENC_CSN_ID, CLMED.SIMPLE_GENERIC_C 
                     ) AS 'FIRST DOSE'
                , RANK() over (Partition by FMED.PAT_ENC_CSN_ID, CLMED.SIMPLE_GENERIC_C order by 
                FMED.TAKEN_DATETIME DESC) 'CYTOTEC_RANK'
                    , ROW_NUMBER() over (Partition by FMED.PAT_ENC_CSN_ID, MEDINFO.MEDICATION_ID order by 
               FMED.TAKEN_DATETIME) AS 'CYTOTEC_ROW'
                , FMED.DISPLAY_NAME
                , FMED.ORDER_MED_ID
                , ORDMED.DESCRIPTION
                , ZCGEN.NAME 
       FROM MED_ADMIN FMED
        LEFT JOIN MEDINFO MEDINFO ON FMED.ORDER_MED_ID = MEDINFO.ORDER_MED_ID
        LEFT JOIN MED ORDMED ON FMED.ORDER_MED_ID = ORDMED.ORDER_MED_ID
        LEFT JOIN MEDICATION CLMED ON MEDINFO.MEDICATION_ID = CLMED.MEDICATION_ID
        LEFT JOIN GENERIC ZCGEN ON CLMED.SIMPLE_GENERIC_C = ZCGEN.SIMPLE_GENERIC_C
        WHERE ZCGEN.NAME = 'miSOPROStol' 
        AND 'CYTOTEC_RANK' = 1
        ) AS [CYT] ON CYT.PAT_ENC_CSN_ID = VITALS.PAT_ENC_CSN_ID
```

Comment: We can't really tell without seeing actual sample data, and the entire query. You might need to simplify your code in order to provide a minimum reproducible example. As a wild guess: presumably, your `left join` comes up empty. Does it work if you put the filter on `CYTOTEC_RANK = 1` in the `ON` clause of the `JOIN` rather than in the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: Here is a sample set of the data that's returned without the where statement. CYTOTEC CYTOTEC FIRST DOSE CYTOTEC_RANK CYTOTEC_ROW
misoprostol (CYTOTEC) 200 MCG tablet 5/6/20 12:53 AM 1 2
misoprostol (CYTOTEC) tablet 1,000 mcg 5/6/20 12:53 AM 2 1
misoprostol (CYTOTEC) tablet 25 mcg 5/6/20 12:53 AM 3 2
misoprostol (CYTOTEC) tablet 25 mcg 5/6/20 12:53 AM 4 1
misoprostol (CYTOTEC) tablet 25 mcg 5/10/20 12:58 AM 1 3
misoprostol (CYTOTEC) tablet 50 mcg 5/3/20 8:43 PM 1 4
... when I put the where cause (rank or row = '1'), all the rows come back null.

Comment: @SHELL, I recommend updating your question so that it contains a minimal reproducible example of the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example  Also placing the sample data in the question body instead of a comment.  As it stands, the query that you included in the question is not valid since it starts with "LEFT OUTER JOIN" and not a SELECT.  Updating your question with that info will make it more likely you'll get more helpful responses.